# Downloaded file is getting saved with jsp filename instead of actual filename

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have written jsp code which downloads files. Here is my code

**Downloadfile.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
    <%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Download</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
int bufSize=2048;
String filePath;

//filePath=getServletContext().getRealPath("")+File.separator+"a.txt";
filePath="D:"+File.separator+"Rain over me.mp3";
File file=new File(filePath);

int length=0;
ServletOutputStream  outStream=response.getOutputStream();
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
response.setContentLength((int)file.length());
String fileName=file.getName();
System.out.println(fileName);
response.setHeader("Content-Diposition", "attachment; filename=\""+fileName+"\"");
byte[] byteBuffer=new byte[bufSize];
DataInputStream inStream=new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
System.out.println("df");
while((inStream!=null)&&((length=inStream.read(byteBuffer))!=-1))
{
    outStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, length);
}

inStream.close();
outStream.close();
System.out.println("df1");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

**sample.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Download</title>
</head>
<body>
Click on the link to download the file<a href="DownloadFile.jsp">Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

After I run the code, the file is getting downloaded with filename **Downloadfile.jsp** instead of **Rain over me.mp3** and also I am getting this below error in console

Aug 30, 2015 2:25:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/FileDownload] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:636)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:214)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:125)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.DownloadFile_jsp._jspService(DownloadFile_jsp.java:113)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Could somebody help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Download</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Downloadfile.jsp" method="post">
   Click on the link to download the file<a href="Rain over   me.mp3">ClickHere</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Harry you request was asking for the file  DownloadFile.jsp

Comment: but upon clicking the link ClickHere it will try to navigate to Rain over me.mp3 instead of DownloadFile.jsp right?

Comment: @Harry No, simply in you link href put a  valid URI to the file you want to download and it will be downloaded, you wont see the file explorer dialog, didn't you try it ?!

Comment: If we cannot see the file explorer dialog then how can we know that whether file got downloaded or not?

Comment: @Harry Dude, when the user clicks on your link in the browser, the rain over me.mp3 file will be downloaded.

Comment: but here nothing is happening upon clicking the link

Comment: only the mp3 file is getting played in the browser instead of downloading

Comment: aha, which means my answer was right :), that's the browsers default behavior, just like for example when you click on a link to a PDF document, the browser displays that document, because the browser understands that MIME type, same applies for mp3, however try for example to create a link for a .jar file it will download automatically.

Comment: if you want to download that mp3 file just use  ctrl+s after clicking the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Harry anytime, but seriously if your not convinced or and need some extra explanation/help, remember that QuakeCore is around:D